# Sortings rows using columns of GridView object returns no results

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have changed the select query of the SqlDataSource object and bind it to the GridView like this

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlBloodGroup.SelectedValue != "Any")
        {
            bg = " And BloodGroup='" + ddlBloodGroup.SelectedValue + "'";
        }
        if (ddlRh.SelectedValue != "Any")
        {

            rh = " And Rh='" + ddlRh.SelectedValue + "'";
        }

        q = "select * from Donor Where 1=1 "+bg+rh;

        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = q;
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

i get the results clearly

but when i click on a column heading to sort by that column the data is gone

Comment: Have you handled Sort by event on grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you have to handle the sorting event**

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlBloodGroup.SelectedValue != "Any")
    {
        bg = " And BloodGroup='" + ddlBloodGroup.SelectedValue + "'";
    }
    if (ddlRh.SelectedValue != "Any")
    {

        rh = " And Rh='" + ddlRh.SelectedValue + "'";
    }

    q = "select * from Donor Where 1=1 "+bg+rh;

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = q;
    SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

and of course you need to ALLOW sorting

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" 
    onsorting="GridView1_Sorting">
```